# Can't debug ASP.Net MVC App in MonoDevelop hosted with mod_mono

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, monodevelop, mod-mono

I am creating an MVC application with MonoDevelop. I have hosted the website on mod_mono under apache, which I installed in my local machine. I've setup a site with custom domain alias like "mymvcsite" and I want to debug my "mymvcsite" with MonoDevelop. My breakpoints are not hit when I run the site with "mymvcsite". I am using MonoDevelop 5.10 and Mono 4.3.2.4 in Ubuntu 14.01.

Comment: what version of mono are you using? what distro and version are you using?

Comment: Hi, how are you attaching to the mod mono process?

Comment: Hello @user1623521, I am running on Ubuntu 14.01 LTS. I am using MONO 4.3.2.4 version.

Comment: Yes @muszeo, I have tried to attached the mod mono process but my breakpoints are not hitting. Thanks.

Comment: how did you install mono?

Comment: @user1623521I have installed the mono from their standard package. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 is two years old, I would recommend upgrading to 16.04 before digging deeper on what might be the problem

Comment: Thanks @user1623521

Comment: I have done the same thing in Ubunti 16.04 LTS and result is same. @user1623521

Comment: I am able debug with custom alias now. I have done this through the nginx reverse proxy. Thanks everyone who helps me in this process.